# Make a html page with content() and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

Is there a way to make an html page from the contents() object??

for example iterate over $('body').contents() object and make a output like this:

```
<body>
<div>text<a href=#></a></div>
<p>%^$$</p>
....
</body>
```

thanks!!! and sorry for the english!

Comment: Could you clarify, are you trying to dynamically generate an entire html page using jquery? or just modify some parts of existing html code?

Comment: yes, i have the content object and i need to generate the web page (or a part) from this object. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at **jQuery append()**.

http://api.jquery.com/append/